# How to open Chrome Browser Network tab and make browser offline using katalon

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, katalon-studio

I had a task to run the test case by making a chrome browser offline and run some steps and then I need to make it back online again and run the rest of the test case.
Can anyone guide me on how to make a chrome browser offline?(**In the network tab of chrome developer tools, it has the option of making it offline.**) I want to make that offline using katalon.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that using Selenium 4. However, that is still in alpha.
Katalon currently supports only [Selenium 3](https://forum.katalon.com/t/can-katalon-work-with-selenium-4/44002).